# How to create table from function and add to docx document

Tags: python, python-docx

I have working code that builds a document with several tables using a for-loop.
To keep the code clean I would like to break out the table creation into its own function but cannot see how to do this from the API doc.

Essentially, I want to call a function to create & return a Table() object and then add it to the document.

Is this do-able?

```
# this works fine

from docx import Document, document, table

document = Document()

table1 = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=4)
     # more table1 building code here

table2 = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=4)
     # more table2 building code here 

document.save('foo.docx')
```

but refactoring like below will not build - I get TypeError: Table.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rows'

```
from docx import Document, document, table

document = Document()

document.add_table(build_mytable(somedata))
document.add_table(build_mytable(someotherdata))



def build_mytable(mydata):
    table = docx.table.Table(rows=1, cols=4)
    # more table building code here
    return table
```

Comment: `rows=...` and `cols= ...` are named arguments of the `add_table` method, so just put the `table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=4)` inside your function, at the start, then write the 'more building code' and return table. Call the function with `table1 = build_mytable(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you try this;

```
from docx import Document 


def create_table(document):
    #this code creates a table with 2 rows and 2 columens 
    table = document.add_table(rows = 2 , cols = 2)
    #adding headers rows 
    hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
    hdr_cells[0].text = 'Item'     
    hdr_cells[1].text = 'quantity'
    
    #second riw 
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells 
    row_cells[0].text = 'Apple'
    row_cells[1].text = '10'


document = Document()
create_table(document)
#save the file 
document.save('tableName.docx')
```

you can then use the add_paragraph method to add more text or other elements ;
or the add_table method to add more tables

for more info you can visit;
Visit https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks - Your solution works well. Note I actually built def create_table(document, mydata):